# How to smooth my deviation curves in RPlot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Long story short, I decided to try a simulation in order to provide some insight upon the reproducability of my data.

However the plot seems pretty awful and I would like to smooth the lines a bit.

The plot is as follows:

1. Scatter: actual data
2. Black Line: Simulated means
3. Red: +/- 2 Standard Deviations

[image]

Comment: Could you add data and your code? It will be easier to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try ggplot's `geom_smooth()`.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

However, this code won't give you the standard deviations, as I haven't got sample data resembling your data structure. Still, you might go from here and set `geom_smooth(se=FALSE)` to get rid of the confidence-intervall area and plot a `geom_area()` with your standard deviations instead.